# How to hide weechat nickname list and channel names?

Tags: weechat

In weechat, how do I hide the nicklist and channel name list?
I'm using weechat in a tmux pane and don't have much room for it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

first find the names of the bars

```
/bar list
```

the nicknames are in `nicklist` and the channel list is `buflist`. Then hide them with

```
/bar hide <bar name>
```

you can also show with

```
/bar show <bar name>
```

and toggle

```
/bar toggle <bar name>
```

you can get more help with `/help bar`

**Bonus** if you want to truncate the timestamps as well you can do `/set weechat.look.buffer_time_format ""`